# How do I get change migration files of existing tabels in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How can I generate the change file from a existing table?

Can I do this with the command line or is this only possible by hand?

I read this [text](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables), but for me it's unclear how the change file will be created?

And if I generate the change file by hand what should be the name from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't *change* migration files, you'll be best creating new ones:

```
$ rails generate migration change_table
```

This will create a *new* migration, which should look something like this:

```
#db/migrate/[timestamp]_change_table.rb
class CreateTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table, :column_name, :type, after: :column
  end
end
```

You'll be best reading up on the [Rails migrations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)